# rsyslog rule inconsistently applied

Tags: logs, syslog, rsyslog

I have created a rule to redirect messages containing {FILTER} in file /etc/rsyslog.d/40-filter.conf

```
:msg,contains,"{FILTER}" /var/log/filter.log
& ~
```

I have edited file /etc/rsyslog.conf so it accepts remote UDP messages by uncommenting lines

```
$ModLoad imudp
$UDPServerRun 514
```

The source of my syslog messages is the following simple python script

```
#! /usr/bin/python

import logging
import logging.handlers

logger = logging.getLogger('LoggingTest')
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

formatter = logging.Formatter('{FILTER} %(message)s')
handler = logging.handlers.SysLogHandler()
handler.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(handler)

logger.info("Test Message")
```

I restarted rsyslog using

```
sudo service rsyslog restart
```

When I run my script the following line appears in /var/log/messages, /var/log/syslog and /var/log/user.log but it does not appear in /var/log/filter.log which exists but remains empty.

```
Jun 23 17:18:29 {FILTER} Test Message
```

If I use command line tool 'logger' (command line example given below) then the rule is applied correctly

```
$ logger "{FILTER} Test Message 2"
$ cat /var/log/filter.log
Jun 23 17:21:28 NDU1010 nick: {FILTER} Test Message 2
```

Why isn't the rule applied to messages from my python script? I'm at a loss to explain this.

Comment: Any thoughts on this? I'm still stumped.

Comment: You noted that you've configured rsyslog to accept remote messages; how is the syslogger configured on the remote machine? Is your manual run of `logger` run from the same remote box as your python script? What about the rest of your log host rsyslogd configuration? (pertinent contents of /etc/rsyslog.{conf,d/*} )

Answer (score 1):

From the output you've given it looks like the python script is not sending all the pieces of the syslog message that rsyslog is expecting.  It appears as if the "{FILTER}" part is where the host and app name should be.  You can pretty easily prove this by running rsyslogd with the -d flag then sending the message from python and then from logger.  You'll see the raw message as it comes from the socket that way and I bet you'll see that logger is sending more fields in front of the "{FILTER}" part.